# How to open another page on my website at Heroku

Tags: html, hyperlink, heroku

At the end of my index.php I put this.

```
<a href="page2.html">Test</a>
```

page2.html exists and I already git pushed it up to Heroku.

When I load the page in my browser, and click on the link I get this error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /page2.html was not found on this server.
```

Why was my page not found?

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't exist.  Check case and paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it wasn't getting uploaded. I had to do `git add page2.html` and then it was sent on the next git push to the server.